# Looking for a TokenFilter

Tags: indexing, solr

I am indexing some files written in spanish in Solr, and sometimes appears chars like  Â¿D  Ã© ....
I wonder if there is some TokenFilter to avoid this chars when the text has accent (á, é, í, ó...)
or letter ñ.

Thanks

Comment: That sounds more like a character encoding problem than something that should be solved with "TokenFilters"

Comment: but i think that with an appropiate Filter or analyzer, i could fix it

Comment: This actually looks more like a charset mismatch. Where do you see Â¿D Ã© ? In your app on in the Solr admin console?

Answer (score 0):

I added it where every other filters are:

> fieldType name="textTight"
>   class="solr.TextField"
>   positionIncrementGap="100" >
>         analyzer>
>           tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
>
> ```
>     filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory"
> ```
>
> synonyms="synonyms.txt"
>   ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
>           ....  !-- Filtro para quitar acentos y ñññ-->
>   charFilter
>   class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" 
>   mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
>           ....
>         /analyzer>
>       /fieldType>

Of course I rebuild my index after that.

(I add this answer, because in the comment it wasn't clear enaugh)

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for a latin language an easier solution is to use

`solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory`

like in :

```
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Romanian" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis for more advance usages.